# How to bring interacted IE browser to the front?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Im using RPA blueprism. Ive 2 interacting browser which is passing data between each other but i cant bring the currently interacted browser to the front. That means the process is running on the back of the first browser. Is there any global action that i can use? Ive managed to get the PID of each browser and ive tried using Focus action on html element but no luck. Do help and TQVM in advanced.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this? If you're using Internet Explorer with HTML mode, I don't see what benefit this would bring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try spying the entire browser as an element and in navigate stage use activate application. it brings the browser to the front.